# How to use animateProperty for TextBox background highlight?

Tags: javascript, animation, dojo

I'm trying to animate a property (`backgroundColor`) of a `dijit/form/TextBox`. I was starting to pull my hair out when this wasn't working:

```
var node = dom.byId("myTextBox");
fx.animateProperty( {
    node : node, 
    duration : 750, 
    properties : {
        backgroundColor : {
            start : "yellow"
        }
    }
}).play();
```

However, this works:

```
var node = dom.byId("myTextBox");
fx.animateProperty( {
    node : node.parentNode.parentNode, // grandparent of "myTextBox" 
    duration : 750, 
    properties : {
        backgroundColor : {
            start : "yellow"
        }
    }
}).play();
```

Is that how it's supposed to work? The examples on [this page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/fx.html#id8) don't need to, but none are using a TextBox either.

Side question: Is there a more direct equivalent to JQueryUI's [`highlight`](http://plugins.jquery.com/ui.effect-highlight/) effect? That's what I'm going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be better for you to get a reference to your widget object with `dijit.byId("myTextBox")` instead. Then you can just reference `myTextBox.domNode` or `myTextBox.focusNode` depending on what you are trying to highlight. I'm not sure if you want the actual text input area to be highlighted or the background, but [this simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zP84X/) demonstrates both. Your code would be changed to something like:

```
var textbox = dijit.byId("myTextBox");
fx.animateProperty( {
    node : textbox.focusNode // If you are trying to highlight the input background 
    duration : 750, 
    properties : {
        backgroundColor : {
            start : "yellow"
        }
    }
}).play();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is leading me in the right direction. I'm using Dojo 1.9 so I think the current recommended way to do this is to use the `dijit/registry` byId instead: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html#dijit-registry-byid

Comment: BTW, after some fiddling I think the reason for the problem is that in claro.css the input area (focusNode) has a background color of 0 0 0 0 (fully transparent) and is marked as important so it can't be overridden (or if it can I haven't figured out how). I added the stylesheet to your example and it demonstrates the issue on the left TextBox: http://jsfiddle.net/blah238/Fb9vT/

Comment: Yep getting the domNode works for me, thanks! Here's a working example *with* claro: http://jsfiddle.net/blah238/xrhFc/